# Verilog - Does a register retain its current value if not explicitly told to do so?

Tags: fpga, verilog

Consider this code:

```
reg myReg [4:0];

always @ ( posedge clk )
begin

    if ( someCondition )

        case ( someValue )

            1       : myReg <= 20;
            2       : myReg <= 31;

            //default : myReg <= myReg;

        endcase
end
```

If the statement `default: myReg <= myReg` is commented out, what happens when `someValue` in the case condition is not `1` or `2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the register will retain its value if not otherwise explicitly assigned.

In fact, this is the reason that people tend to create inadvertent latches in combinatorial code (`always @* ...`) when they forget to create explicit assignments for every register for every path through the code.